# Dividing ranges to each other and multi conditionals

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-conditions

I want to create a multi criteria Worksheet Function in VBA according to this excel formula

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,A:A/(B:B="YES")*(C:C="NO"),1)
```

I don't want using direct excel  formula method like `=AGGREGATE(14,6....`. The purpose is creating the logic with `WorksheetFucnction` method.

The main issue is dividing ranges by each other: for example RANGE("A:A")/(RANGE("B:B")="YES") and multi criteria are also problem.

I have tried:

```
WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(14,6,Range("A:A")/(Range("B:B")="YES")*(Range("C:C")="NO"),1)
```

But problem arises when it comes down to dividing ranges to each other.

Please share any other method to do this task.

Comment: Use `Worksheet.Evaluate` and pass the formula as text.

Comment: BraX, I have already written, that I dont want to use "formula as text" method. My puprpose is just converting this formula to WorksheetFunction.Please advise me in this direction if you can.

Comment: You can't. It is not possible to use a construct like `Range("A:A")/(Range("B:B")="YES")`, or `(Range("C:C")="NO")`,  inside a `WorksheetFunction`. When you asked "any other method to do this task", I gave you one: `Worksheet.Evaluate`.